# The "divide" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Can anyone figure out what it's supposed to be about? It has no usage guidance and anything from voltage/current/frequency dividers to floating-point division algorithms seems to be in there.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divide

There are no tags for divide**r** or division.

We probably don't want the SO tags as-is, but for the sake of comparison:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/division "In mathematics, division (÷) is an arithmetic elementary operation."
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/divide: "Separate or be separated into parts" (Meh) They also have a ["split"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/split) tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a pretty vague tag, and not very widely used -- looks like only 17 questions "in all time" and 4 in the past month. The most upvoted questions tagged [divide](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divide) seem to be about:

- Arithmetic division (1/x) (i.e. multiplicative inverse) on a microcontroller or in HDL
- Frequency division (i.e. prescaler)
- Analog division of Voltage (analog computer / operational amplifier)
- A circuit analysis question about current division in parallel resistors
- and most recently, a downvoted question that seems to be about separating an 8 bit number into two 4 bit fields.

I guess it may add some value as clarification when paired with another tag, but by itself it's pretty ambiguous. I think the value of having question tags is to make it easier to find relevant questions (for those who bother doing research before posting), and also makes it possible for subject matter experts to notice new questions with that tag.

There is already an existing tag [voltage-divider](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage-divider), so perhaps

- create [frequency-divider](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frequency-divider) (for prescalers and counters producing one output frequency from a higher input frequency. Not to be confused with frequency-division multiplexed RF modulation.)
- create [arithmetic-division](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic-division) (for microcontroller or FPGA/HDL calculating arithmetic 1/x or performing integer modulus division)
- create [analog-computer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analog-computer) (for operational amplifier circuits that perform math operations such as add / multiply / divide / log / exponent )
- retag all 17 questions as appropriate
- burninate [divide](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divide).

Comment: i agree with Mark.

Comment: I've just created those three tags.

Comment: Oh and I found [a question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143786/binary-polynomial-division-on-fpga-implementation) about polynomial division in FPGA :p

Comment: And one a but a current divider. I've created a tag for that for now, but perhaps it should be in the same bucket as voltage divider... not sure.

Comment: I'm gonna use/create "polynomial-math" for the polynomial division question... so we have some tag commonality with SO on this; seems ok in this case.